# Will Cassandra return tombstone rows as valid rows?

Tags: cassandra

My idea is to add rows to Cassandra with `TTL = 15 minutes` so I'll be able to load realtime data `(now - 15 minutes, now)` w/o storing timestamps etc. My concern is that the rows with expiring TTL will be marked as tombstone (not actually deleted). I.e., will they count when I run `select count(*) from realtime_table`?

Answer (score 3):

No, tombstoned rows won't be returned as a result - they will be skipped when reading the data.

But if you actively expiring the data, you may need to tune `gc_grace_period`, otherwise you can get too many not removed tombstones, and in some cases will start to get warning or error during read if read operation will need to skip tombstones (controlled by [tombstone_warn_threshold](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html#configCassandra_yaml__tombstone_warn_threshold) & by [tombstone_failure_threshold](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html#configCassandra_yaml__tombstone_failure_threshold) options of `cassandra.yaml`.

Here is the [very good blog post](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html) that describes how data are deleted & cleaned up.

But `select count(*) from table` is real antipattern in Cassandra - you need to consider correct modelling of your data with partitions, etc.